# Erro ao Executar uma query com npgsql + dapper no postgresql

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, postgresql, dapper

Eu consigo captar meu objeto "usuario" que tem dentro de si um "Login e uma Senha" e, ao executar a função pelo meu ORM, capto a seguinte mensagem de erro:

> {"42883: operador não existe: @ character varying"}.

Alguém saberia me dizer o que pode estar ocasionando tal erro?
Segue abaixo a função para executar a query..

```
  public Usuario Login(Usuario user)
  {
      return this._db.Query<Usuario>("SELECT nome, login, senha FROM usuario WHERE login = @Login and senha = @Senha", new { user }).FirstOrDefault();
  }
```

Comment: E os parâmetros, está passando onde?

Answer (score 1):

A sua query define dois parâmetros: `@Login` e `@Senha`. Eles precisam ser passados através de um objeto anônimo no método `Query`:

```
public Usuario Login(Usuario user)
{
    return this._db.Query<Usuario>("SELECT nome, login, senha FROM usuario WHERE login = @Login and senha = @Senha", new { Login = "login_do_usuario", Senha = "senha_do_usuario" }).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Comment: na realidade se o objeto "user"  contiver esses paramentos idênticos o dapper se vira para pegar o valor de cada parâmetro corretamente.